# How to set the mime about red5

Tags: red5

How to make the red5 video server, identify non. Flv streaming media file extension.
By setting the mime, so red5 can play custom file extensions celebrity media files.
All video files are encoded flv, just changed the extension.
thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you've changed your flv files extensions to something besides .flv? Not sure why you'd do that, since it will take custom coding to get them to playback in red5.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I use ffmpeg for video encoding. Other video formats into flv, convert after I modified the file extension. This is required by the manager

Comment: I made a video coding using ffmpeg. After the other to FLV video format conversion, I modified the file extension. This is a requirement for the manager. I hope red5 to recognize this extension, play it. Do you have any Suggestions or ideas? Thanks for your help.